# An inequality relating to moves to P-positions in Nim

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have been researching this variant of Nim. I have been unable to prove the following claim. What is annoying is that I feel I am missing something really obvious. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this:

Let's first say that one position dominates another if all its corresponding pile sizes are at least as great. Note that the positions must be distinct. For example, $(1,2,4)$ dominates $(0,1,4)$ whereas $(5,8,7)$ does not dominate $(4,2,8)$.

Here is the actual problem. Let $m$ be a positive odd integer and $\oplus$ denote the bitwise xor. Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative integers with the following conditions:

1. $a \oplus b \geq m$
2. $0 < a < \frac{m}{2} \leq b < m \leq c$

Show that for all integers $0 \leq i < m$, there exists a position $(a^\prime,b^\prime,c^\prime)$ dominated by $(a,b,c)$ such that:

1. $a^\prime + b^\prime + c^\prime = 2i$
2. $a^\prime \oplus b^\prime \oplus c^\prime = 0$

Comment: OK joriki. Thats a good point. I will do that. :-)

Comment: Note that $c'=a'\oplus b'$ yields $a'+b'+c'=a'+b'+(a'\oplus b')=2(a'\cdot b')=2i$, so $(a',b',c')$ is $(a',b',a'\oplus b')$ with $a'\cdot b'=i$ (where $\cdot$ denotes bitwise or).

Comment: Thank you so much joriki. I never thought about using the bitwise or. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote yet.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: This means that I have to show the existence of a position $(a^\prime,b^\prime)$ dominated by $(a,b)$ such that $a^\prime \cdot b^\prime = i$. By the way, is $\cdot$ the standard for bitor like $\oplus$ is for bitxor.

Comment: Are you saying that the dominance of $c$ over $c'=a'\oplus b'$ would then be guaranteed? That's not obvious to me.

Comment: $(a^\prime \oplus b^\prime) + a + b  = 2i < 2m$. Now, we also have that $ a + b \geq a \oplus  b \geq m$. So, $a + b \geq m$. Therefore, because $c > m$, you can say that $ a + b + c > 2m$. Comparing with the first statement, we have that $(a^\prime \oplus b^\prime) + a + b  < a + b +c$ which means that $a^\prime \oplus b^\prime < c$. Please tell me if I have made an error.

Comment: That was a typo. I have fixed it.

Comment: That seems right; I think it should be $c\ge m$ and $a+b+c\ge 2m$, but the conclusion remains valid. This means that $(a',b')$ doesn't have to be strictly dominated by $(a,b)$; we can allow $(a',b')=(a,b)$, since $c$ strictly dominates $c'$.

Comment: Yes it should me $c \geq m$.

Comment: Since $a'\oplus b'\oplus c'=0$ says that either $0$ or $2$ bits in $a',b',c'$ are set in each position and $a'\cdot b'=i$ says that $0$ bits in $a',b'$ at a position are set iff the corresponding bit of $i$ is not set, we can view the bits set in $i$ as specifying the positions in which $a',b',c'$ have $2$ bits set.

Comment: So if $i'\cdot i=i'$, a solution for $i'$ yields a solution for $i$ (by clearing the corresponding bits in $a',b',c'$). So we only need to check the $i$ values that don't have such an $i'\neq i$.

Comment: So, this problem is really stating that we can choose make those 2 bit sets happen all the way up to $m$. The bounding conditions basically bound the number of binary digits and the bitxor condition makes sure that a and b do not have too little filled digits.

Comment: Doesn't every value of $i$ besides $0$ have such an $i^\prime$. Just remove the leading digit.

Comment: The bitwise or should yield $i'$, not $i$. So you'd have to add a digit, not remove one, and you can't add a digit to all values of $i$. Still, an only slightly more complicated construction allows the problem to be reduced to the maximal value $i=m-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $c'=a'+b'=a'\oplus b'=i$. Then at each position, exactly $0$ or $1$ bits are set in $a'$ and $b'$ depending on whether the corresponding bit in $i$ is set. It remains to be decided how to distribute the set bits in $i$ over $a'$ and $b'$. Obtain $a',b'$ from $a,b$ as follows: Clear all bits that are cleared in $i$. Since $a\oplus b\ge m\gt i$, the most significant bit change from $a\oplus b$ to $i$ is $1\to0$, and that bit was set and gets cleared in one of $a'$ and $b'$, say, $a'$. Change all bits in $a'$ that are set in $i$ but not in $a\oplus b$.

Since the most significant changed bit is worth more than all less significant changes added together, we have $a'\le a$ and $b'\le b$, and also $c'=i\lt m\lt c$, so $(a',b',c')$ thus constructed is dominated by $(a,b,c)$. Note that $a\lt\frac m2\le b\lt m$ hasn't been used.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.